# ignore_invalid_triggers not working

Tags: python, transition

I am using the pytransitions library ([documented here](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions)) to implement a Finite State Machine. One of the features outlined is the ability to ignore invalid triggers. Here is the example as per the documentation:

```
 # Globally suppress invalid trigger exceptions
 m = Machine(lump, states, initial='solid', ignore_invalid_triggers=True)
```

If the trigger is set to true, no error should be thrown for triggers that are invalid.

Here is a sample of the code I am trying to construct:

```
from transitions import Machine

states = ['changes ongoing', 'changes complete', 'changes pushed', 'code reviewed', 'merged']
triggers = ['git commit', 'git push', 'got plus2', 'merged']

# Initialize the state machine
git_user = Machine(states=states, initial=states[0], ignore_invalid_triggers=True, ordered_transitions=True)
# Create the FSM using the data provided
for i in range(len(triggers)):
    git_user.add_transition(trigger=triggers[i], source=states[i], dest=states[i+1])

print(git_user.state)
git_user.trigger('git commit')
print(git_user.state)
git_user.trigger('invalid') # This line will throw an AttributeError
```

The produced error:

```
changes ongoing
changes complete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/transitions/core.py", line 58, in _get_trigger
    raise AttributeError("Model has no trigger named '%s'" % trigger_name)
AttributeError: Model has no trigger named 'invalid'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am unsure of why an error is being thrown when ignore_invalid_triggers=True.
There is limited information on this library besides the documentation on the official github page. If anyone has any insight on this I would appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Sorry about that. I posted in a hurry. I have edited and made it more clear as well as adding sample code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be an invalid trigger under the rules set out in the documentation, the trigger name has to be valid *somewhere* in the model. For instance, try trigger "merged" from state "changes ongoing".  You get an attribute error because "invalid" is *not* a trigger at all: you have a list of four, and that's not one of them.

To see the effect of establishing "invalid" as a trigger, add an end-to-start transition (the last line below) after your nice linear loop:

```
# Create the FSM using the data provided
for i in range(len(triggers)):
    git_user.add_transition(trigger=triggers[i], source=states[i], dest=states[i+1])
git_user.add_transition(trigger="invalid", source=states[-1], dest=states[0])
```

*Now* your code should run as expected, ignoring that invalid transition.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand how it works now.